# Multiple Combobox selection Acess VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I am trying to create a VBA code that says, if combobox equals this or this or this then have radio button populate. When i use only one bucket (134) it works fine but when i try ti add multiple sections, i get and err.

My code:

```
If Me.cmbBucketFilter = "134,135,136" Then
    'Working Echo Triggers
    Me.fmeReached.Visible = True
    Me.fmeRecovered.Visible = True
    Me.fmeError.Visible = False
      Else
    'Working Another Bucket
    Me.fmeError.Visible = True
    Me.fmeReached.Visible = False
    Me.fmeRecovered.Visible = False
  End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking it to run only if cmbBucketFilter equals "134, 135, 136" (which it never can).  What you really want is for it to run if it equals **any** of those values.

Change the first line to this:

```
If Me.cmbBucketFilter IN ("134", "135", "136") Then
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much for replying. When i try to use what you suggested, I get an error. "Complie Error: Expected: Then or GoTo.

Comment: Baically what im trying to do is, If Me.cmbBucketFiler = 134 or 135 or 136 then...